# mit Harn beschmutzen

Tags: sentence-structure

> mit Harn beschmutzen

Duden has given the above phrase as a meaning of the verb "be­spren­zen".
If the verb "be­spren­zen" takes an accusative object then why the accusative citation is not shown in the phrase "mit Harn beschmutzen"?

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/besprenzen

Comment: Just a side note: that is a word that’s so not longer used today, as also stated in the link. While I admire your zeal, this is probably not worth putting much effort into, imho. And different verbs (even with comparable meaning) can follow totally different grammar patterns,

Comment: Grimms Wörterbuch already labels the word as *no longer in use*, but  makes no statement to the the type of liquid involved, neither do the given examples (of before 1920).

Answer (score 1):

There are some fishy steps in your argument:

1. Verbs that have the same meaning might take different case. (Stephie's comment).
2. *mit Harn beschmutzen* **is** governed by accusative, but not because a synonym verb is, but because of *beschmutzen*.
3. The accusative is probably not shown, because Duden does not show it for other verbs either. You can deduce it from the given examples and/or look it up in other dictionary.